# mockhttpservletrequest spock returning null

Tags: grails, spock

I'm trying to write a that needs to the `request.getHeader('X-File-Size')` to return a Long. So I tried to write the test like this:

```
given:
  MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest()
  request.getHeader('X-File-Size') >> 2L

when:
  controller.handle()

then:
  1 * serviceMock.upload(_ as Long)
```

And this is what my controller looks like:

```
def handle() {
  def fileSize = request.getHeader('X-File-Size') as Long
  uploadFileService.upload(fileSize)
}
```

But it says that I am passing a null to the service method instead of a string. I thought the mock would return a long instead of a null.

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code:

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest()
```

You don't create a mock but a real object. To create a mocked object You need to use `Mock` or `GroovyMock` method from test's superclass (should be `Specification`). So:

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = Mock()//GroovyMock()
request.getHeader('X-File-Size') >> 2L
```

Comment: Oh. The name is very misleading. Why can't I just do `HttpServletRequest request = Mock()`?

Comment: No idea. Provide a sample project then maybe I can help You.

Answer (score 0):

Once a [mock request](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.4/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers) is available when testing controllers, have you tried this?

```
setup:
    def key = 'X-File-Size'
    def value = 2L
    request.addHeader(key, value)

when:
    controller.handle()

then:
    1 * serviceMock.upload(value)
```